# using paint that has been frozen

Tags: repainting

I used some latex paint that had bee frozen. it had a granulated texture but that was no matter for the project I had. I have heard this will crack and peel faster. what if I paint over it with good paint will it cause problems with that too or will a coat of new paint prevent the premature peeling? basically do I have to remove the layer of bad paint or can i just paint over it?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a weak layer of paint, adding strong layers won't help, as it will still crack and peel at that weak layer. I'd suggest waiting and seeing what happens; if it lasts as-is then you're good, if it starts peeling then you'll have a head start on removing it.